# 我爷爷的全身很疼，他不能去游泳: Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, simplified-characters

> 他对我说：“我爷爷的全身很疼，他不能去游泳”

Is the entire sentence grammatically correct? I'm not sure about "的". 
Should I remove it or just leave it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 他对我说：“我爷爷的全身很疼，他不能去游泳”

的 in 我爷爷的 (My grandpa's) is a possessive marker, therefore follow it with a noun '全身' is  grammatically correct. But 的 can be omitted here

我爷爷的全身 = 我爷爷全身

Native Chinese would write "我爷爷全身[都]很疼" [所以]他不能去游泳” (My grandpa's whole body is [all] in pain, [therefore], he can't go swimming)

Answer (score 1):

我爷爷的全身很疼 sounds ok.

but 我爷爷全身很疼 sounds better.  我爷爷 is topic.  我爷爷"怎么样"？(我爷爷)全身很疼。